# Inconnu ou inconnue (d'une équation)

Tags: orthographe, écriture

Je sais qu'il faut écrire

> équation à une inconnu**e** ou l'inconnu**e** ou bien une inconnu**e** (d'une équation)

J'ai quelques étudiants qui écrivent l'inconnu (ou bien un inconnu). Est-il erroné ou pas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour ma part, dans le cadre d'une équation, c'est toujours **une** inconnu**e**.

Comment: Donc, l'inconnu (dans ce contexte) est tout simplement une faute d'orthographe, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @Dimitris Oui. Ça peut arriver, une simple faute d'accord, mais je crois ne jamais avoir vu ou entendu "*un inconnu*" dans ce contexte.

Comment: Merci. À propos, c'est une faute persistante:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris: Effectivement c'est une faute

Comment: @Dimitris: Je ne veux pas généraliser, mais souvent les étudiants (en sciences, mais pas seulement) ont une orthographe que je qualifierais de “relâchée” ; pour ne pas être méchant.

Comment: Le problème est que ce n'est pas une simple coquille...Le même étudiant peut le commettre plusieurs fois dans son document (sujet par exemple) et en plus pas mal d'étudiants le font. Pour cette raison j'ai dit faute persistante:-)!

Comment: Orthographe relâchée ! J'adore cette expression! Merci pour l'idée. Tu me permets de la voler ? Vive le FSE :-)!

Comment: @Dimitris: Pas de soucis, c'est *freeware* ;)

Comment: @LPH: Effectivement, une erreur de frappe.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que vos élèves ont tort. Wikipédia l'écrit au féminin ([Inconnue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconnue_(math%C3%A9matiques))). Je pense que c'est parce que c'est une **variable** inconnue ou bien une **valeur** inconnue - tous deux des noms féminins.